# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^s} = -2^{-s}(2^{s}-2)\zeta(s)$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory

> Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^s} = -2^{-s}(2^{s}-2)\zeta(s)$ for $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.

I can't seem to find a proof or come up with a proof for this identity.I tried using fourier series for some polynomial functions. But I always end up with nasty Integrals involving the incomplete gamma function with complex entries.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function

Comment: LHS is analytic for $\Re s >0$ by general properties of Dirichlet series: RHS is entire by general properties of $\zeta$; they are equal on $\Re s >1$ by term by term computation with Dirichlet series, so they are equal on $\Re s >0$ by analytic continuation

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} & =-\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n+1)^s}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n)^s}\right] \\
& =-\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 n)^s}\right] \\
& =-\left[\zeta(s)-2^{1-s}  \zeta(s)\right] \\
& =-2^{-s}\left(2^s-2\right) \zeta(s)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer!!!